# Laravel, trait to create additional record during saving?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, traits, laravel-5.6

I want to save additional record in database while saving a model in laravel, my model looks like:

```
class Document extends Model
{
    use DocumentSetup;
}
```

And my trait looks like:

```
trait DocumentSetup {
    protected static function boot()
    {
        static::saving(function ($model) {
            $documentSetup = new DocumentSetup();
            $documentSetup->document_id = $model->id;
            $documentSetup->is_public = false;
            $documentSetup->need_verification = true;
            $documentSetup->save();
        });

        parent::boot();
    }
}
```

If I try that I don't get any error, but document or document setup are not created, does anyone know what i'm doing wrong here?

My idea is to create this additional model while saving...

Comment: I'm not sure why this isn't working but I just write an observer class and then in the boot method use `static::observe(ObserverClass::class);` and that seems to work well.

Comment: How are you saving the `Document` model that should trigger this event?

Comment: Also, I guess parent::boot() should be the first statement in case if used. Can you try changing that to the first statement?

Comment: @DakshMehta I moved it to top already, but the same problem

Comment: Can you provide us with the code you used to save the Document?

Comment: `$document = Document::firstOrCreate(['doccode' => $doc['doccode']], $doc);`

Comment: Does `firstOrCreate()` actually create a new document in your case? Or does it just find an existing one?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir it creates also a new document

Answer (score 2):

When using traits for Eloquent lifecycle hooks, you must name the boot method `boot[traitName]` in your case `bootDocumentSetup`. You should also remove the `parent::boot()` call in the trait, as there is no such parent call. If you name it like this it will work.

This is to avoid clashes when you are using one or more traits in a model, that each have its own boot method.

Comment: Should be noted that you also remove the parent::boot(); call when doing this as there's no longer a parent version of the method.